# Why do we say "אשר ציוונו להדליק נר של חנוכה" while the decree is rabinical

Tags: blessing, chanuka

The Hannuka blessing is saying "אשר ציוונו" but  the decree is rabbinical.
Isn't this mis-speaking and thus disregarding of "מדבר שקר תרחק"?

Can you quote recorded debates (if any) over this issue, and explain the different arguments?

Comment: netillat yadayim, hallel, megillah, eiruv, shabbat candles...